# Error with Python3 and OpenCV3 while slicing image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, jenkins

I've been trying to modernize a python2 script to python3 and after struggling with the errors I've narrowed it down to the following error.

```
def slicePage(image):
    # area of the little rectangles next to the sentences, relative to image size
    rect_area = 0.00035 * image.shape[0] * image.shape[1]

    # threashold image and detect contours
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    *_,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours,*_ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # find the little rectangles next to the sentences
    squares = []
    for cnt in contours:
        cnt_len = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
        cnt = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.1*cnt_len, True)
        if len(cnt) == 4 and cv2.contourArea(cnt) > rect_area:
            cnt = cnt.reshape(-1, 2)
            squares.append(cnt)

    # check if number of squares fits pattern
    if (len(squares) == 0) or (len(squares) % len(ITEMS) != 0) or (len(squares) / len(ITEMS) > MAX_SENTENCES_PER_PAGE):
        return None

    # items start below the highest point of each square
    cut_y = sorted([min([p[1] for p in sq]) for sq in squares])

    # use right-most point to start looking for the vertical black line
    max_x = max([max([p[0] for p in sq]) for sq in squares]) + 1
    # from the first rectangle, walk right until hitting the line
    line = thresh[cut_y[0], max_x:]
    line_start = np.where( line < 255 )[0][0]
    cut_x = max_x + line_start + np.where( line[line_start:] == 255 )[0][0]

    # adjust y-values if they intersect with any of the text
    for i in range(len(cut_y)):
        counter = 10        
        # there should not be any non-white pixels on the vertical line
        while len(np.where( thresh[cut_y[i], cut_x:] < 255 )[0]) > 0 and counter > 0:
            counter -= 1
            cut_y[i] -= 2

    slices = []
    for i in range(len(cut_y)):
        top = cut_y[i]
        bottom = cut_y[i+1] if i+1 < len(cut_y) else image.shape[0]
        left = cut_x; right = image.shape[1]
        area_thresh = thresh[top:bottom, left:right]

        # cut off whitspace
        yBlackRange = np.where(np.min(area_thresh, axis=1) < 255)[0]
        bottom = top + yBlackRange[-1]
        top = top + yBlackRange[0]
        xBlackRange = np.where(np.min(area_thresh, axis=0) < 255)[0]
        right = left + xBlackRange[-1]
        left = left + xBlackRange[0]        

        slices.append(image[top:bottom, left:right])

    return slices
```

The main error that I get is narrowed down to this chunk

```
   # find the little rectangles next to the sentences
    squares = []
    for cnt in contours:
        cnt_len = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
        cnt = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.1*cnt_len, True)
        if len(cnt) == 4 and cv2.contourArea(cnt) > rect_area:
            cnt = cnt.reshape(-1, 2)
            squares.append(cnt)
```

I'm using **Python3** ( anaconda ) and **OpenCV3**. The error I'm running into is related to imagedesc feature in OpenCV3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-51-7586a536b1c0>", line 5, in <module>
    cnt_len = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)

error: /Users/jenkins/miniconda/1/x64/conda-bld/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:281: error: (-215) count >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function arcLength
```

Comment: Did you happen to port this from OpenCV 2.x code? In 3.x `cv2.findContours` [returns a tuple with 3 values](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html), rather than 2. You're actually trying to iterate over an image, rather than a list of contours.

Comment: Yes, you've guessed it right. Thanks the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains the following:

> `contours,*_ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

However, you should not that the return value of `cv2.findContours` has changed between OpenCV 2.x and OpenCV 3.x. As such, instead of iterating over a list of contours, you're actually trying to iterate over an image.

The [contours tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) from the 3.x documentation shows how to capture the results correctly.

#### OpenCV 2.x

```
>>> import cv2
>>> print cv2.__version__
2.4.11
>>> help(cv2.findContours)
Help on built-in function findContours in module cv2:

findContours(...)
    findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> contours, hierarchy
```

#### OpenCV 3.x

```
>>> import cv2
>>> print cv2.__version__
3.1.0
>>> help(cv2.findContours)
Help on built-in function findContours:

findContours(...)
    findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> image, contours, hierarchy
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like one or more of the values in `contours` is violating this check - `count >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)`. For the first check, just make sure that every value is positive. As for the second check, you probably know more than me about what depth refers to :)

Comment: Well, I've tried to debug it by printing the ` len(cnt)` inside the slicePage function - right above the `squares = []`  prints out `1773` but still unable to make sense of it.

Comment: It looks like the link Dan Mašek cited has the answer

Comment: While this is a correct observation, and there's nothing wrong with suggesting to debug, I think that this is more of a comment rather than an answer, as it does not explain the (somewhat obscure) source of the actual problem.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to write comments yet. I'll bear your comment in mind.

Comment: No worries, we all had to start some way (BTW, I think the commenting issue is now over ;) )

Comment: Oh, I think this is helpful! Thanks @DanMašek :+1: